# PHP Loop though an textarea list.

Tags: php, mysql, loops

See the code below. The polist is from a textarea field. It loops thought the array. This line produces as expected **echo $line . "
";** The PO Number is echoed. But the output from the query on v_devices only list the items from the last PO number in the list from the textarea.

Any ideas why? Any help would be most appreciated!!

```html
 if(isset($_POST['polist'])){
  $polist=$_POST['polist'];
  $text = trim($polist);
  $textAr = explode("\n", $text);
  $textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim');

  foreach($textAr as $line) {
         
         $result10 = $db->select(
                "SELECT * FROM `v_devices` WHERE `ponumber` = :po",
                array ("po" => $line)
        );

echo $line . "<br>";
            foreach($result10 as $row10) {  
                $poline = $line . "," . $row10['organization'] . "," . $row10['serialn'] . "," . $row10['model'];
                echo $poline . "<br>";               
            }
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Can you show your src textarea, your current output and your desired output?

Comment: You mean this line? `<textarea name="polist" wrap="off" id="polist" style="width:250px;height:200px;"><?php echo($polist); ?></textarea>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in the `foreach($textAr as $line)` loop you keep overwriting `$result10` variable that holds the resultset of the query and you print out the results after the loop.

Either move the printing part into into this loop, or you need to add the result of the query to the `$result10` variable.